# How do I declare the root element of an XML document in the XSD schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am working on a problem for XML class, and I am new at it. My XSD file validates. The XML file has the following validation error: Cannot find the declaration of element 'catalog'. The XSD filename is catalog.xsd and the XSD code where the element "catalog" is declared is

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" />
   <xs:element name="date" type="xs:string" />
   <xs:attribute name="metadata" type="xs:string" />
   <xs:attribute name="cid" type="cidType" />
   <xs:attribute name="src" type="srcType" />
   <xs:attribute name="donatedBy" type="xs:string" />


   <xs:simpleType name="cidType">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:ID">
         <xs:pattern value="c\d{4}" />
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>

   <xs:simpleType name="srcType">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]+.jpg" />
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>

   <xs:complexType name="catalog">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="photo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
```

I have been able to resolve all other validation errors, so the two files appear to be referencing each other properly. Is there a step I have missed? Should the "catalog" element be declared in another way?

Thank you!

I am adding the XML code, I did think that perhaps I was missing something there. The file name for the xml is catalog.xml.

```
<catalog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="catalog.xsd">

   <photo cid="c1748" donatedBy="John Borelli">
      <name metadata="tunis cooper property museum">Tunis R. Cooper property</name>
      <description>
      <![CDATA[ 
         This photo was taken by John Borelli's great-grandfather. It is believed to have been taken around 1830.
         David Demarest originally purchased the site of the chair factory in 1663. This site was under the ownership 
         of the Demarest family until 1758.  The property is listed in the National and New Jersey Registers of Historic Places.
      ]]>
      </description>
      <date>circa 1830</date>
      <images>
         <img src="1748a.jpg" />
         <img src="1748b.jpg" />
      </images>
   </photo>
```

Comment: The main schema needs an INCLUDE to reference the second schema.  Most schema have optional properties that are sometimes declared in a different schema.  So you need to add an INCLUDE in the main schema to the other schema.  It would be put on 2nd line of schema and look like this : <xs:include schemaLocation="Common.xsd"/>

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your headline question is, you can't. XSD by design considers every subtree of a valid element to be valid in its own right, and to ensure that this property holds, it doesn't allow the schema to say that element E is a legitimate validation root when its children F, G, and H aren't.

But reading past the headline, that's not your problem. You don't need to declare that catalog is the root element of the document, you just need to declare it.

And from what you have shown, it looks as if you have done so. The two most likely reasons for the error are therefore:

(a) your instance document is actually rooted at a catalog element in a different namespace

(b) you didn't actually succeed in loading this schema document and supplying it to the validator. You say that you have "resolved other validation errors" so this suggests you are picking up the schema, so perhaps (a) is more likely.

To diagnose (a) we would need to see the instance document. To diagnose (b) we would need to see how you are invoking the schema validator.

Comment: Thank you! I did suspect, but had no vocabulary for, a problem with how I am referencing the namespace.  I edited my original post to include that part of the code. :) I am also trying to help another student in the class, and of course teaching someone else helps me understand the concept a little better.

Comment: OK, well with this new information it's now clear that the instance document has `catalog` in no namespace, and the schema defies `catalog` in no namespace. So the error can only be that this schema isn't being picked up at all; and that must be because of the way you invoked the validation.